# Which is or are grammatically correct: "Cats are carnivores / carnivorous or carnivorous animals"?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, differences

> Cats are carnivores
>   Cats are carnivorous
>   Cats are carnivorous animals

I often hear people say those sentences and I wonder which among them is/are correct. And are there any differences in meaning or focus among the three sentences?

Comment: They are all valid and essentially mean the same thing.

Comment: @Jim They are all valid but do not mean the same thing.

Comment: @Kris- waiting to pounce I see.  That's why I said *essentially*.  Obviously the 3rd admits to a cat being an animal while the 1st only implies it because a *carnivore* **is** an animal that eats meat. The second uses *carnivorous* which just attaches the qualities of being a carnivore to the cat. But all this is evident by the words that are present in each.  There is no subtle hidden difference that a native speaker would perceive that a non-native speaker would miss.  They are all quite straightforward in their meanings, which is: Cats eat meat.

Comment: @Jim bravo and correct.

Comment: @Kris. They are all valid, they do mean the same thing although some additionally mean further things, Jim carefully wrote "essentially", and if you're going to be a smarty-pants you have to read very closely :)

Comment: @Jim Would you use them interchangeably?

Comment: Sundews are carnivorous.

Comment: @Jim If you restrict the definition of 'carnivore' to 'an animal that eats meat', you end up with a mismatch as there are certainly carnivorous plants.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- That's true my dictionary gives two definitions- the first is about animals that eat meat, the second about plants. I don't think anyone's likely to try to apply def. 2 to a cat though.

Comment: I would go further than Jim and say there's hardly a dime's worth of difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from emphasis and rhythm, the only difference I can think of is that in certain contexts, "carnivore" could refer very specifically to a member of the order Carnivora. However, an actual scientist would probably say "carnivoran" or "member of the order Carnivora," and most people don't make the distinction, so that's rare.

Comment: Of course not all members of Carnivora are actually carnivorous.